# Show the output of my programm in the executable jar file

Tags: java

I have implemented app server application. The connection works based on the TCP. When I run the server side and click something in the app. Protocol steps are being validated until the process is accomplished. During
the processing String messages are being output in the Eclipse console. The server side programm has two classes (one with main method). The programm does not have any  Swing component. I made the server side as
executable jar file but I can not see any output!? How can I manange to print the messages in a window to see the output when making the programm as executable jar file?

Comment: You should see the output to `stdout` (e.g. with `System.out.println(...);` when you start the jar from a terminal , so the messages are being printed to the console by default. When you start the jar with a double click or whatever the output is not shown, in Eclipse the output is redirected to the internal message console.

Comment: @xander: Thank you I am getting the ouput now.